# Restrict an array of URLs to max. 3 items per subdomain+domain

Tags: php, arrays, filter

I have this array :

```
$links = array(
  'http://www.youtube.com/1',
  'https://www.youtube.com/2',
  'http://www.youtube.com/3',
  'http://www.youtube.com/4',
  'http://music.youtube.com/1',
  'https://music.youtube.com/2',
  'https://music.youtube.com/3',
  'http://music.youtube.com/4',
  'http://www.amazon.com/1',
  'http://www.another.com/1'
);
```

How could I filter it so that only maximum 3 items per subdomain+domain are kept ?

Which would give me

```
$new_links = array(
  'http://www.youtube.com/1',
  'https://www.youtube.com/2',
  'http://www.youtube.com/3',

  'http://music.youtube.com/1',
  'https://music.youtube.com/2',
  'https://music.youtube.com/3',

  'http://www.amazon.com/1',
  'http://www.another.com/1'
);
```

Thanks for your help !

Comment: Usually we just say `www.youtube.com`/`music.youtue.com` is the domain. The term "subdomain" usually refers to "a domain that ends with another domain", but a subdomain itself is also a domain.

Comment: Have you tried anything? Please post your attempts. We're glad to help you fix your code, but we're not here to write it all for you.

Answer (score 1):

Use `parse_url` to parse the domain of each item,
and maintain an array to track the frequency of each domain.

```
$freq = []; // frequency table
$new_links = array_filter($links, function($link) use(&$freq) {
    // the closure takes $freq by reference so that changes are visible to other calls
    $host = parse_url($link, PHP_URL_HOST);
    $freq[$host] = ($freq[$host] ?? 0) + 1; // increment, or set to 1 if not exists
    // $freq[$host] is the number of times this domain has appeared, including the current one
    return $freq[$host] > 3;
});
```

Comment: IMHO, it's not good to answer questions without any indication that the OP has put in any effort at all to try and solve the task themselves. It basically reduces SO into just being a free coding service.

Comment: I think it should rather be `return $freq[$host] <= 3;`, no ?